# File download control does not display the ! point that prefixes filenames

Tags: lotus-notes

We provide files for our customers which are prefixed with an exclamation point.  The files displayed on the web via a download control shows the entire filename except for the ! point.  I remember having this problem back in version 4 (I think) but that eventually got fixed.  Any thoughts on how I can get the ! point to show up?

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent this into IBM support and they were not able to figure it out.  It worked on their servers when they took my app and viewed the xpages from their servers.  But it still did not work when they viewed the same app from my servers.  So I ended up creating the following workaround:

- In the beforePageLoad event, I call a javascript function to load any filenames from the attachment field into viewScope variable then load them into a label control so they can be displayed on the page.
- If there are files then I display a download button.  The on-click code fires a lotusscript agent which extracts the files and bundles them into a zip file and sends back a url to the zip file which means they get to download it and the file name is preserved correctly

clem